# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. IN ADFS and single sign on

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, single-sign-on, adfs, windows-identity

I m using ADFS for single sign on with my asp.net MVC application.
Now all is working fine except one thing only.
When my fedauth cookie will get expire or some intentionally delete it and make AJAX request
it throws an error as mentioned below.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy' is therefore not allowed access.